# Can I run Apache, mod_wsgi and MongoDB within virtualenv?

Tags: apache, python-2.7, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

I'm learning about `virtualenv` and `mod_wsgi` and these are my favourite articles so far:

https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments
(by the author of `mod_wsgi`, Graham Dumpleton).

http://www.dabapps.com/blog/introduction-to-pip-and-virtualenv-python/

I understand that `virtualenv` allows me to have independent instances of Python and Python packages.

But how does this relate to things like `Apache`, `mod_wsgi` and `MongoDB`?

Can these things also be included in this virtual environment?

The scenario I am interested in is being apple to have a local application that is 'self reliant' (that would be easy to install on other systems) - `virtualenv` seems to enable this to an extent, but can `Apache`, `mod_wsgi` and `MongoDB` only exist at this broader 'system level' or can they exist in a virtual environment?

Comment: do you mean you want a "virtual" apache? and a "virtual mongodb"? because these are servers.not environments. though you can think about vagrant or docker for this.

Answer (score 0):

`virtualenv` is for python packages only, <strike>so you cannot have instances of system applications running within in it, like apache</strike>.

**Edit**: As mentioned by @Graham Dumpleton, it is possible to install apache httpd using [mod_wsgi-httpd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi-httpd) inside `virtualenv`. But, as I said earlier virtualenv is for python packages, so it is a matter of finding/writing a package that solves the problem.

That being said, you can make Apache, that uses mod_wsgi, to take advantage of `virtualenv`. Trick is, configuration has to be done within a python file.

Say you are trying to setup django project `myproject`, that is running within virtualenv named `myproject`, here is your `wsgi.py`:

```
import os, sys, site

path = os.path.split(os.path.dirname(__file__))[0]
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

site.addsitedir('~/.virtualenvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'

activate_env=os.path.expanduser(
    "~/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Configuration for apache or mongodb wouldn't be any different, since they are system wide running services.

Comment: Not entirely true. You can install Apache into a virtualenv and mod_wsgi installed into that can use it when using mod_wsgi-express. It is a way around out of date Apache and mod_wsgi on a system. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi-httpd https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi