# mod_wsgi and virtualenv - Invalid command 'WSGIPythonHome'

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

**Desired Behaviour**

I want Apache to use the `mod_wsgi`that is installed in `virtualenv`, rather than relying on a `mod_wsgi` installed at system level.  I'm assuming that this is possible because that is what I thought`virtualenv` was for, ie creating isolated environments.

**Current Behaviour**

*Environment*:  Linux Mint 17

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start

AH00526: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:
Invalid command 'WSGIPythonHome', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included
in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf**

```
WSGIPythonHome /var/www/html/ENV
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html:/var/www/html/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/myapp/app.wsgi

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**What I've Tried**

If I install `mod_wsgi` via Synaptic Package Manager at the system level, then everything works as expected.

If I *uninstall* `mod_wsgi` via Synaptic Package Manager at the system level, and just rely on the `mod_wsgi` that has been installed via `pip` in `virtualenv`, then I get the errors above.

I've been referring to this, but can't glean any particular solutions from it for this issue:

https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On reflection, I am guessing now that as `mod_wsgi` is an Apache module, it is not possible for it to run within `virtualenv`, in the same way Apache can't run within `virtualenv`, so therefore `mod_wsgi` needs to be installed at the system level for it to work.

Also see:

[Can I run Apache, mod_wsgi and MongoDB within virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27126694/can-i-run-apache-mod-wsgi-and-mongodb-within-virtualenv)

And this is the configuration I ended up using:

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf**

```
WSGIPythonHome /var/www/html/ENV
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html:/var/www/html/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/var/www/html/wsgi
<VirtualHost *:80>

    # for all content in static folder - css, js, img, fonts
    Alias /static/ /var/www/html/wsgi/static/

    # for rockmongo
    Alias /rockmongo /var/www/html/rockmongo

    <Directory /var/www/html/rockmongo>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/wsgi/application

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```